# Unable to connect to IIS express, using DNX beta5

Tags: iis, single-page-application, iis-express, dnx

After I updated VS2015 yesterday and I cannot run my project (singla page app) anymore... Visual Studio says: Unable to connect to IIS express

I am using Solution DNX SDK version: 1.0.0-beta5

[image]

And my project.json is:

[image]

My references:

[image]

So everything should be ok ??

What am I doing wrong ?

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand that direct IIS hosting is no longer supported (and probably never will be again)! This is a decision by the ASP.Net team at Microsoft to completely concentrate on the kestrel server which is anyway required for Mac/Linux/Docker. By concentrating on one server the quality rises for everyone. Like Node, Kestrel recommends to use a reverse proxy in front of it. For that you can use your IIS/nginx/Apache.

I would urgently recommend you setup your project with RC1 and change to kestrel with HTTPPlatformHandler (in VS2015 Update 1 that works transparently with IIS Express for you). Beta5 is very outdated for many things.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! I did as you mentioned I installed RC1 and changed server.iis to Server.Kestrel and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible that your project could take a few hours before being able to run again.

First, you skipped `beta6`, `beta7`, `beta8` and we are now at `RC1`.

Check which runtime you can use in Visual Studio and make sure you run with the latest one.

Once this is done, ensure that all your dependencies branded `beta5` are renamed to the proper version that is in your Visual Studio. Some packages may have been removed, classes moved and many other things.

Check here for breaking changes:

- [Changes in `beta6`](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/milestones/1.0.0-beta6)
- [Changes in `beta7`](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/milestones/1.0.0-beta7)
- [Changes in `beta8`](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/milestones/1.0.0-beta8)
- [Changes in `rc1`](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/milestones/1.0.0-rc1)

Comment: Hi the higest DNX SDK version is 1.0.0-beta8. I changed it to beta8 everywhere except in project.json, the dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS only allows up to beta7 ?? When I do this the iis express seems to work but vs drop out of debug mode immediately after launch. In the output the DNX complains about not finding or cannot open the PDB file